# Creating a connection in Java from a Data Source in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've followed this support article https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-importing-data-sources.html#d1262242e18746 to create a new Data Source in IntelliJ. Testing the connection is successful. But I can't find any example on how to create a new connection and get a data reader back in Java using this new data source. Where can I get info on how to reference this data source in Java?

I'm coming from .NET, so hopefully I'm not thinking about this backwards.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The link in the question is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do what you trying to do. This IntelliJ features creates a connection to your database and allows you to access it from IntelliJ without the need of having a workbench open.

Comment: So this feature is just a replacement for a MySQL/DB IDE?